# "Finish work" or "finish my work"?

Tags: difference, possessive-adjectives

Tell me please if there any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> Yesterday I finished **my** work at 6.
>
> Yesterday I finished work at 6.

If there is no difference, then is it more common to use *my* or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small difference in *connotation*.

In common usage, "finished work," most often, means the **work-day had ended** at 6.

"I finished my work," *could* mean the same, but could also imply that a **task was completed** at 6.