# "finished my work" vs. "finished with my work"

Tags: meaning

I understand the typical usage of "finish", like "[I finished my work](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/236397/117396)", "[She finished (the concert) with a song from her first album](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/finish)."

[From the Free Dictionary by Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+from+work)

> off from work: **Finished with one's work** for the day.

Assume Daniel was off from work at 6:00 pm yesterday. With the definition, could I say like this?

> Daniel **finished with one's work** for the day at 6:00 pm yesterday.

Daniel finished what with whose work?

I tried [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finish%20my%20work%2Cfinish%20with%20my%20work%2Cfinished%20the%20work%2Cfinished%20with%20the%20work%2C%20finished%20my%20work&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinish%20my%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20the%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20with%20the%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20my%20work%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfinish%20my%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20the%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20with%20the%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfinished%20my%20work%3B%2Cc0) but didn't get any clue.

[image]

Comment: *I've finished work* is the natural way of saying that your working day has ended (it's now after "clocking-off time"). Therefore if a competent native speaker introduces an additional ***unnecessary*** preposition *(I've finished **with** work)*, other native speakers will naturally assume some ***different*** meaning is intended. In that particular case, the most likely alternative would be that the speaker means ***I'm completely fed up with working, and don't intend to work ever again*** (maybe he's just exaggerating, maybe he's actually *retiring*, or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you could not say that!

*Finished with one's work* is the dictionary's explanation of what *off from work* means. *One* is simply whoever happens to be the subject of the sentence.

You would have to say *Daniel was finished with his work for the day...*  - but it would be simpler to say *Daniel was off from work* or *Daniel finished work.*

Comment: Things get clearer. Thank you. Regarding "Daniel was finished with his work for the day", Daniel is a person, does "**a person was finished** with something" sound natural?

Comment: I suppose so, if you have some reason for not naming that person.